# angular material, show dialog from a component that is lazily loaded

Tags: angular, angular-material-8

I have a lazy loaded module, named `account`. In `account` there's a `RegisterComponent` and a `RegisterDialogComponent`.

I'd like to show a dialog from `AccountModule.RegisterDialogComponent` in `AppModule.AppComponent`. For testing purposes.

`RegisterDialogComponent` is declared and in entrycomponents, in the `AccountModule`.

If I add the `AccountModule` to `AppModule`'s imports it works, but then this `AccountModule` isn't lazily loaded anymore.

My question is, how do I open a dialog with content from a lazy loaded module? Is that even possible?

Comment: the modal should be in the shared module if you are sharing across application

Comment: So it's not possible to show a dialog from a lazy loaded module? A shared module is not lazy loaded.

Comment: Either you create that modal in your current module/ if you are using across application you can't

Comment: alright, thank you for the response

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, at least I don't know how.

The workaround is to have everything regarding the dialog and the components in their own module, aka same scope. This will however still not allow to open a dialog from an external module if this account module is lazy loaded. But it will allow to open a dialog in the lazy loaded module from the lazy loaded module. Long term, account features are a core part of an application and as much as I'd like it, it has to be included in the initial bulk of js files being loaded.

Note that even if lazily loaded, you have to add your local `DialogService` to providers, even though it's `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})`. And of course the DialogComponent needs to be in `entryComponents`.